# Testing a shell command interpretor

Tags: c, unit-testing, bash

I've written tests that use Bash for testing a custom shell. I think the tests work but I'm sure you know better because this is my first test I write this way.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "-- Testing our implementation of OpenShell --"
echo ""
echo "- If you have any problem in passing a test read the corresponding"
echo "- source file to understand what the test is checking"
echo ""
echo -n "********************* PRESS ENTER TO RUN TESTS  ... "
read answ
echo ls -al openshell.*|./shell
echo -n "********************* TEST ALGORITHMS ... "
read answ
./shell < <(echo "ls -al|grep open|awk '{print \$9}'")
echo -n "********************* TEST DONE. YOU SHOULD SEE FILENAMES ABOVE ... "
```

Now I run the test and see what I expect, my command interpreter executes the pipeline from the Bash script.

```
$ ./RUN_TESTS 
-- Testing our implementation of OpenShell --

- If you have any problem in passing a test read the corresponding
- source file to understand what the test is checking

********************* PRESS ENTER TO RUN TESTS  ... 
Current working dir: /home/dac/ClionProjects/shell2/openshell
'PATH' is set to /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin.
stdin is a file or a pipe

p[0][0] ls
p[0][1] -al
p[0][2] openshell.h

-rw-rw-r-- 1 dac dac 1439 maj  1 16:45 openshell.h
********************* TEST ALGORITHMS ... 
Current working dir: /home/dac/ClionProjects/shell2/openshell
'PATH' is set to /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin.
stdin is a file or a pipe
 {ls} {-al} {|} {grep} {open} {|} {awk} {{print $9}} {|}
p[0][0] ls
p[0][1] -al
p[1][0] grep
p[1][1] open
p[2][0] awk
p[2][1] {print $9}

openshell-0.16430.tar.gz
openshell.h
********************* TEST DONE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of multiple `echo` statements, consider using a *here document*:

```
cat <<EOF
-- Testing our implementation of OpenShell --

- If you have any problem in passing a test read the corresponding
- source file to understand what the test is checking
EOF
```

To `echo` an empty line, you can write `echo` without parameters instead of `echo`.

The flags of `echo` are not portable. Instead of `echo -n`, you can use `printf`.

If you don't need the user input, you don't need a parameter for `read`.

Parsing the output of `ls -l` is considered a bad practice.

Instead of this:

```
./shell < <(echo "...")
```

You can use a *here string*:

```
./shell <<< "..."
```

Some vertical space (blank lines) can improve the readability of your code.

Putting it all together, your script would be better this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat << EOF
-- Testing our implementation of OpenShell --

- If you have any problem in passing a test read the corresponding
- source file to understand what the test is checking

EOF
printf "********************* PRESS ENTER TO RUN TESTS  ... "
read

echo ls -al openshell.* | ./shell
printf "********************* TEST ALGORITHMS ... "
read

./shell <<< "ls -al|grep open|awk '{print \$9}'"
printf "********************* TEST DONE. YOU SHOULD SEE FILENAMES ABOVE ... "
```

***Update***

As per your follow-up question, and as @Mat pointed out, neither `<(cmd)` nor here-strings will work in dash. To make the last statement work, you could use a here document:

```
./shell << EOF
ls -al|grep open|awk '{print \$9}'
EOF
```

Comment: Will it also work with `dash` and `ksh` since I'm targeting OpenBSD and Ubuntu? ? Since I'm writing a shell myself that we call `osh`, can I use my shell version 0.97 to test my shell version 1.0 ?

Comment: Yes, or should work in dash and ksh too

Comment: Why did you say this: "_Parsing the output of ls -l is considered a bad practice._" ? Why is it so? I changed the test and asked about it again [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/317316/is-this-test-good-enough). Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Programmer400: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs; I don't think _here strings_ are portable (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism says not), and process substitution isn't available on all OSes.

Comment: Thanks @Mat, I actually misunderstood the question. Added a paragraph about this to my answer